# Run classic asp code after page has loaded

Tags: asp-classic

How can I run the asp code after the page has loaded? I'm trying to make the page load quicker and then display the content in a ajax loaded page. I'm animating to the page and the animation is not starting before the asp code has loaded, so thats why I want to load the page first and then run the asp code.
Any input appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `Response.Flush` after sending the HTML head section.
This will give the browser time to load stylesheets/scripts while the Server is busy generating the output.

Make sure to delay the content generation after the call to `Response.Flush` to accomplish this.

Pseudocode:

```
Response.Write "<DOCTYPE html>"
Response.Write "<html><head>....</head><body>"
Response.Flush ' output so far is sent to the client

' load data from database
dim s_content
s_content = buildPageContent()
Response.Write s_content

Response.Write "</body></html>"
```